# bulk copy data from 1 model to another in django

Tags: django, model

I am having 2 model of similar schema and I want to bulk copy from `model1` to `model2`  but `model2` is having 3 more fields but I want to store null in these fields.

```
class SubscriberBalanceProcess(models.Model):


    VOICE_SOC = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    SMS_SOC = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    DATA_SOC = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    DATE_TIME = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    TOTAL_REMAIN_VOICE = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    TOTAL_REMAIN_SMS = models.BigIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    TOTAL_REMAIN_DATA = models.BigIntegerField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)


    class Meta:
        db_table = "SUBSCRIBER_BALANCE_PROCESS_TEST"

class SubscriberBalance(models.Model):


    VOICE_SOC = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    SMS_SOC = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    DATA_SOC = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    DATE_TIME = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    FILE_ID = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'subscriber_balance'




SubscriberBalanceProcess.objects.bulk_create(SubscriberBalance.objects.filter(VOICE_STATUS='N', SMS_FLAG=1, TENANT_ID__in=loginIdList))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 353, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 345, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
>   348, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line
>   399, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\Development\Desktop\python\crons\management\commands\sendsms_voicebalance_process_rule_tarif.py",
>   line 74, in handle
>       self.sendsmsVoicebalance()   File "C:\Users\Development\Desktop\python\crons\management\commands\sendsms_voicebalance_process_rule_tarif.py",
>   line 30, in sendsms Voicebalance
>       activeMVNO = Functions.updateNonRuleMatchRecordByTarif(categoryId, type)   File
>   "C:\Users\Development\Desktop\python\crons\includes\functions.py",
>   line 49, in updateNonRuleMatchRecordByTarif
>       Functions.truncateUpdateVoice(loginIdList)   File "C:\Users\Development\Desktop\python\crons\includes\functions.py",
>   line 64, in truncateUpdateVoice
>       SubscriberBalanceProcess.objects.bulk_create(SubscriberBalance.objects.filter(VOICE_STATUS='N',
>   SMS_FLAG=1, TENANT_ID__in=loginIdL ist))   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122,
>   in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 447,
>   in bulk_create
>       self._batched_insert(objs_with_pk, fields, batch_size)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1056,
>   in _batched_insert
>       using=self.db)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 122,
>   in manager_method
>       return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1039,
>   in _insert
>       return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
>   line 1059, in execute_sql
>       for sql, params in self.as_sql():   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line
>   1019, in as_sql
>       for obj in self.query.objs   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line
>   968, in pre_save_val
>       return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py",
>   line 702, in pre_save
>       return getattr(model_instance, self.attname)
>
> AttributeError: 'SubscriberBalance' object has no attribute
>   'TOTAL_REMAIN_VOICE'

Comment: Please try to mend your question after [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please read the following on how to format code (and stack traces): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you can't just feed `SubscriberBalance` objects to the `SubscriberBalanceProcess` creation function.
You should make proper instances first with data of the common fields:

```
queryset = (SubscriberBalance.objects
            .filter(VOICE_STATUS='N', SMS_FLAG=1, TENANT_ID__in=loginIdList)
            .values('VOICE_SOC', 'SMS_SOC', 'DATA_SOC', 'DATE_TIME', 'FILE_ID'))

new_objects = [SubscriberBalanceProcess(**values) for values in queryset]

SubscriberBalanceProcess.objects.bulk_create(new_objects)
```